Selenium C#, opening small Edge browser and unable to maximize the browser window
We're expanding our automation regression testing to include the Edge browser as well. Presently, we've been employing Selenium 4.19, driverManager 2.17.2, and .Net 4.7.2.
However, when attempting to launch the EDGE browser using the following code, it opens in a very small window (Edge app) without even displaying the URL, and unable to expand manually too.
Despite trying various code snippets from the Selenium documentation, none have proven successful.
Could you assist me in opening the normal Edge browser using driverManager without specifying the Edge.exe path?
Here is the code I have used.
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
Driver = new EdgeDriver(options);

Edge browser image


From the screenshot, your organization configured this policy BrowserSignin to Force so that users must sign into a profile to use the browser. In this situation, you need to use a signed in profile to open Edge when automation then the sign in popup won't show and you can maximize the browser window.
First, please find the user data dir of the signed in profile you need to use. You can open this page edge://version/ in Edge and find Profile path:

You can add the value of Profile path to Edge options like below, please don't include the last profile folder part:
options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data");

If the profile folder is Default, you only need to add the above code. If it's Profile 1, Profile 2 or other numbers of profile, you also need to add this option:
options.AddArgument("profile-directory=Profile 1");

Note: Please change the path to your owns in the code.
